# get the value from the first row field one2many

Tags: python, odoo

I have a field one2many for the display manufacturing order. 
I want to display the code of manufacturing orders in the first row in the tree view.
 how can i do that ??

Comment: queston is not clear explain it clearly

Comment: ok, i have table one2many(manufacturing order) in form view. then, i want to display MO number (reference) from first row data table in tree view, how to do that?

Comment: so,you want a child item's value in  tree view of parent ?

Comment: i add new column in tree view with name MO(manufacturing Order). the value for this column take from first row in table one2many in form view(just take column reference)..

Comment: can u please post your xml code.